# How to assign custom fonts for the Dialog Box appearance?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, toolbox

I am developing a Toolbox for ArcGIS Desktop. All the work have been almost completed and I am writing the item description for the toolbox.
The description fonts are not what I want and I'd like to change the fonts. Here are my questions:

1. Is this possible to assign custom fonts for the Dialog box descriptions?
2. How can I do that in a way that sharing the toolbox does not ruin this? (Custom font appears for different users and computers)

P.S. I have read this article but I did not understand what to do.
http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/documenting_tools_and_toolboxes/changing_tool_dialog_appearance.htm

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply: No. You cannot do anything from within ArcGIS to change the font on the tool dialog. The only possible way to change this would be at the operating system level, but that will change fonts for everything and it's not a solution you can deploy to others.

Comment: The point which I may have missed explaining is that the picture I have attached is not the actual dialog. Do you mean that using style-sheets it is not possible to assign some fonts for the tools which are made with ModelBuilder? @KHibma